# VBA code find the date value

Tags: vba, excel

In my excel I have some date values and my vba code cannot find it. Even with Ctrl+F I cannot find the date in my excel workbook. The dates are written as followed: 4-5-2018(d-m-year)

My vba code is:

```
Sub kopieermacro()

' kopieermacro Macro
'
'

    Dim a As String
    Dim b As String
    Dim zoeken As Worksheet
    Dim datum As Date


     ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E18,N2:N18,O2:O18").Copy


     a = Worksheets("Berekenen").OLEObjects("cmbsheet").Object.Value
     Sheets(a).Activate
     datum = CDate(InputBox("voer datum in"))

     Set zoeken = Sheets(a).Cells.Find(What:=(datum))
     If Not zoeken Is Nothing Then
         zoeken.Select
         ActiveCell.Offset(rowoffset:=2, columnoffset:=0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
     Else
        MsgBox "Zoeken is Nothing"
     End If  
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you try to modify your Find function like this:  Sheets(a).Cells.Find(What::=DateValue(datum), LookIn:=xlvalues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

Comment: If you click on a cell with a date, how (exactly) does it display in the **[formula bar](http://cdn.solveyourtech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/excel-2010-unhide-formula-bar-3.jpg)**?

Comment: I connected the cells with each other. for example Cell B1+1 will display 02-05-2018. My formula bar will look like this: =B1+1

Comment: And `B1` on it's own is... `01-05-2018`?

Comment: When using CTRL+F to find, make sure you change the Option for "Search In" to "Values".  Also, I think @M.R. 's suggestion above is probably what you need, for the same reason: looking in the **Values**

Comment: If your cells contain Strings rather than true Dates, you would need to use *Find* with a String of similar format.

Comment: that is true B1 on its own is 1-5-2018 which has the cell value Date. However the vba error now shows error 13 (type mismatch).